# How to Prevent your Andriod app to minimize

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Is there any way to not going my app in minimize state in android Studio when I press home button or I show the dialog box if user conform it then app minimize any one please help me

I also use `onUserLeaveHint()`
function but it only shows me the state.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this, the closest thing you can get is an alert dialog when the user taps the back key

```
public void onBackPressed() {  
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
    builder.setCancelable(false);  
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to Exit?");  
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
            //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application  
            finish();  
        }  
    });  
    builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
            //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app  
            dialog.cancel();  
        }  
    });  
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();  
    alert.show();  
}     
}
```

Comment: this is for back button press but i want like this for home button